# My youtube-v3-api search request doesn't always send back the same result

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making regular query on my youtube channel with the youtube-v3-api , searching a specific word, used in the title of some videos.

Unfortunately, It doesn't always send back the same results.

Can it be links to the fact I've placed my key word at the end of the video title? Maybe the videos are too old, and the keyword wasn't here when the video was originally uploaded?

I need a sure way to return all the videos containing a certain keyword, without having some videos disappearing mysteriously between two queries.

Comment: If you always expect the same result, why query again in the first place?

Comment: what is the request query that you use for this?

Comment: www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=OUR_QUERY&maxResults=50&part =snippet&type=video&order=date&channelId=YOUTUBE_CHAN_ID&key=APP_KEY

Comment: I tried your request, and it seems like it is normal, maybe you can also post here the channel ID that you are using and what query you use for us to replicate your work